# % doesn't work when editing Haskell code in vim?

Tags: haskell, vim

When I put the cursor on a parenthesis in vim:

```
f = (\x y -> x+y)
    ^
```

typing `%` will move the cursor to the matching parenthesis:

```
f = (\x y -> x+y)
                ^
```

typing `%d` will delete the parentheses and everything in them

```
f = 
   ^
```

but when I have nested parentheses:

```
g = (\(x,y) -> x+y)
    ^
```

typing `%` makes it jump to the closing inner parenthesis instead of the matching one:

```
g = (\(x,y) -> x+y)
          ^
```

and `%d` has the same mismatching behavior:

```
g = (\(x,y) -> x+y)
    ^
```

becomes

```
g =  -> x+y) 
    ^
```

Why? How can I make it match properly?

---

Oddly, the visual highlighting of matching parentheses does work:

[image: a]
[image: b]
[image: c]
[image: d]
[image: e]
[image: f]

How does this work but then the matching by `%` doesn't? Are there two brains?

Comment: I've actually been annoyed by this forever but never thought to ask here. Thanks!

Answer (score 12):

Short answer, from [`:help %`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/motion.html#%):

```
:set cpoptions+=M
```

This prevents vim from ignoring the `\(` combination and treat it as `(`.

(The long answer might involve using a similar plugin to matchit, of which I am unaware, that explains to vim that `\` means lambda, not backslash.)

Comment: @Dog In your .vimrc consider adding `autocmd FileType haskell set cpoptions+=M`

Comment: This seems to work, except now handling of regex strings doesn't work. For example in this code, `regex = "((\(blah)...)"`, put the cursor on the second `(`. It goes to the last `)` instead of the first. Also, strangely again, the visual highlighting behavior seems to completely unaffected by whether I do `:set cpoptions+=M`